# Any good community translation tools for Android?

Tags: android, translation

One of my applications is getting more and more popular, and I'd like to support multiple languages, but there are a few problems:

1. I don't know every single language out there
2. I'm actively developing the application, so strings change and new ones are added - often

That's why I've been looking at the possibilities of an online community translation tool. I'd like for it to be free and open source, and it'd be great if it supports Android!

Sorry if this is off-topic, I was a bit unsure, but I think it's a problem that many Android developers have to deal with.

Comment: If you are not going to support, for example, Asian languages that are very different from English in structure, online tool may work, but if you are, you might embarrass yourself by using such tools. I would recommend simply using translation services that are so cheap these days.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that the strings are ever changing and that I continue adding new ones almost all the time. Online translation services wouldn't work well in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WordPress for Android we use [GlotPress](http://glotpress.trac.wordpress.org/), you can upload your strings.xml and it will create sub projects for whatever language you want. You can then invite users to translate the project to their native language.

Comment: Should have probably pointed out that I am in fact using WordPress, but that seems like an excellent idea! Up vote for the link and suggestion, will approve it when I get to try it out :)

Comment: Thanks again, excellent piece of software. Seems like it's still in the early phases, but it works well. If you want other people to be able to help you translate, you should install it alongside WordPress. This blog post covers it well: http://remkusdevries.com/how-to-use-glotpress-for-your-translations/

Comment: Cool, hope it works out for you. You can see it in action for our app at http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/android/dev

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working just fine - and perfect with the WordPress integration. Mine's up and running on http://mizuu.tv/translation/projects/mizuu-translation/ :-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to handle string-array , or am i missing something ?